# Abstract functions and data types -- is there any elegant way to do this?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a large family of objects all descended from a single parent.  The objects all know how to tell if they have been modified, but I also need to be able to see if a new instance of an object has been modified compared to one I already have in memory (testing to see if someone else updated the database while the object was being edited.)

The result is that every child class has to contain the same method:

```
public new bool Changed()
{
    return Changed(this);
}
```

This really sticks in my craw but I see no way around it as the real work needs to be done by a function that takes a parameter of the same type as the class it's in — thus it can't be virtual.  (Sure, I could define it to take the parent and cast it each time but that makes the comparison function accept any object in the tree rather than only the right one, and it requires the guard code in each instance, again something ugly.)

Of course this works but I dislike ugly code.

Update: As for the `Changed` function, each object retains a copy of its state when it's been loaded.

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate on your `Changed()`, share some concrete example. I could adjust my example according to that

Comment: `Changed(SomeDerivedType o)` is implemented in each of the derived classes? A few lines with an example of your base class and a derived class really would help along :-) I'll call it a night now

Comment: @skarmats: You're right that each derived class implements Changed(<it's own type> o).  Each checks it's own fields and calls the base to check any parent fields.

Answer (score 3):

As long as your base class is `abstract`, you can do something like this:

```
abstract class Base
{
    public abstract bool Changed<T>(T obj) where T : Base;

    public bool Changed()
    {
        return Changed(this);
    }
}

class Subclass : Base
{
    public override bool Changed<Subclass>(Subclass obj)
    {
        // Do stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: It *LOOKS* like what I want--but it doesn't compile.  I'm not sure what's happening but the parameter contains only the fields of the parent, not the fields of the current class that I need to look at.

Comment: The only thing I might change is to make Changed of T to be protected. I would think you would want to always call the base Changed external to the class.

Comment: I just tried a test case and get the same results. Becuase of the constraint on the generic to clases derrived from Base, the method can only see the members of Base.

Comment: Found a work around. You can cast the obj parameter to a fully qualified name of the type and get access to the properties: MyNamespace.Subclass refObj = obj as MyNamespace.Subclass. You can get to all the props via refObj then. If you do not use the full namespace it appears to still think its the of T parameter

Answer (score 2):

The basic structure:

```
public abstract class Base<T> where T : Base<T>
{
    public T Original { get; private set; }

    public abstract bool Changed(T o);

    public bool Changed()
    {
        return this.Changed(Original);
    }
}

public class DerivedA : Base<DerivedA>
{
    public override bool Changed(DerivedA o)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class DerivedB : Base<DerivedB>
{
    public override bool Changed(DerivedB o)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

While it has its cons (readiblity), it could be the right choice in this case, since your issue isn't type protection in the classical Animal/Dog/Cat sense, but code sharing.

To prevent this scenario:

```
public class DerivedC : DerivedB
{
}
new DerivedB().Changed(new DerivedC()); // compiles
```

you could seal `DerivedB`.

Or you could continue the craziness (I would not recommend this. Definitely not further than this level):

```
public abstract class DerivedE<T> : Base<DerivedE<T>> where T : DerivedE<T>
{
}

public class DerivedF : DerivedE<DerivedF>
{
}

public class DerivedG : DerivedE<DerivedG>
{
}

new DerivedF().Changed(new DerivedG()); // does not compile
new DerivedF().Changed(new DerivedF()); // does compile
```

See this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx. I got the inspiration from that article. He discusses cons and pros.

EDIT: Cleaned-up, adjusted according to comments

Comment: Another answer that doesn't compile:  It complains the type is not generic and can't be used as a type argument.

Comment: My basic example does compile. Please share a bit more about your code and I'd be happy to look into it. See my comment on the OP

Comment: I didn't say the derived classes aren't getting inherited, some of them are.  Anyway, the error is "The non-generic type <DerivedName> cannot be used with type arguments", it's thrown on the class line.

Comment: You do need to apply the principle I showcased above to your own classes. If you don't declare your base class generic, this cannot work.

Comment: I invite you to play around with my basic example to get a feel for the solution

Comment: Oh, I see what I did wrong--I was declaring the generic on the child, not the parent.  It still doesn't like it, though--the Changed function that started this whole mess won't compile, "this" isn't compatible with "Parent<T>".

Comment: I just now added another example at the bottom. Cast it to `T` basically. Maybe I can come up with something better tomorrow. Good night :)

Comment: @LorenPechtel: Well, I came back to it ;) Updated with better solution and some clean-up

Comment: I think this is getting beyond what I would consider elegant.

Comment: @LorenPechtel. Haha, you might be right. Although it solves the problem succintly at least for the first level of inheritance. It also  signals clearly the intent which comparisons should be allowed. The members I introduced should have an existing equivalent in your code if I didn't misunderstand completely.

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as minitech, so he should get the credit, but in this example the Changed of SubclassA can see its properties by casting to the fully named class.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    abstract class Base 
    {     
        protected abstract bool Changed<T>(T obj) where T : Base;      
        public bool Changed()     
        {         
            return Changed(this);     
        }

        public String PropBase { get; set; }
    }  

    class SubclassA : Base 
    {
        public String PropA { get; set; }

        protected override bool Changed<SubclassA>(SubclassA obj)     
        {
            ConsoleApplication1.SubclassA myInstance = obj as ConsoleApplication1.SubclassA;
            // Now can see PropA
            myInstance.PropA = "A";
            return true;
        }


    }

    class SubclassB : Base
    {
        protected override bool Changed<SubclassB>(SubclassB obj)
        {
            // can't see prop B here 
            // obj.PropB = "B";
            return true;
        }

        public String PropB { get; set; }
    } 


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            SubclassB x = new SubclassB();

            x.Changed();

            Base y = new SubclassA();

            y.Changed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm really puzzled here--it still doesn't see it even with the cast!

Comment: What version of .Net are you tageting ? This works for me in .Net 4.0

Comment: Test case works for both .Net 3.5 and .Net 4.0. Note that I do have SP1 for .Net 4.0 and VS2010 installed.